# Reloading video.js player after changing source using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I manage to make a script where I can change the video source without reloading the whole page, but the problem is that after the new source is loaded, the player is not and I only get a black box.

**HTML:**

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls autoplay preload="auto" width="850" height="400" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source id="videoMP4" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
<div class="menu1">menu1</div>
<div class="menu2">menu2</div>
<div class="menu3">menu3</div>
<div class="menu4">menu4</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".menu1").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("example_video_1").innerHTML = "<source src=\"http:\/\/video-js.zencoder.com\/oceans-clip.mp4\" type='video\/mp4' \/>";
});
$(".menu2").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("example_video_1").innerHTML = "<source src=\"http:\/\/techslides.com\/demos\/sample-videos\/small.mp4\" type='video\/mp4' \/>";
});
$(".menu3").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("example_video_1").innerHTML = "<source src=\"http:\/\/video-js.zencoder.com\/oceans-clip.mp4\" type='video\/mp4' \/>";
});
$(".menu4").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("example_video_1").innerHTML = "<source src=\"http:\/\/techslides.com\/demos\/sample-videos\/small.mp4\" type='video\/mp4' \/>";
});
```

Full code and example: http://codepen.io/BeBeINC/pen/PqydVM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `.load()` function. You should pause it to prevent the audio from keeping on playing.

```
var video = document.getElementById('example_video');
var source = document.getElementById('videoMP4');
$("ELEMENT").click(function() {
    video.pause()
    source.setAttribute('src', 'NEW MP4');
    video.load();
    video.play();
});
```

Comment: It does change the source and reloads the player, but the same old video restarts: http://codepen.io/BeBeINC/pen/OVaJOz

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that

```
var player = videojs(document.querySelector('.video-js'));
  player.src({
                 src: 'videoURL,
                  type: 'video/mp4'/*video type*/
            });

  player.play();
```

Comment: this worked for me using type: 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl' ... in fact, calling load() actually caused it to break!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the video's source using the player's API, specifically the [src()](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#src-source-) method:

```
yourPlayer.src("http://foo.com/bar.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

just do it this after you filled other attributes by JS:

```
$('#player')[0].load();
```

Comment: Adding explanation of your code will be great. Code only answers are discouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I Faced Similar Problem  But Solved it By Changing the Poster source dynamically first then accessing the vjs poster class and changing its style, have a look at code :

```
$('#videoPlayer video').attr('poster', "https://dummyimage.com/hd1080");
```

document.querySelector("vjs-poster")[0].style.backgroundImage = "https://dummyimage.com/hd1080";